# Typing a map with a polymorphic type

Tags: flowtype

I am trying to type a function that takes a map of keys and functions and applies them to an object that if it contains the key present in the map applies the function on that key to the value on the object property. Right now I am hung up on typing my map of transformation functions:

```
export type Normalizer<A, B> = (value: A) => B;
const stringToBool: Normalizer<string, boolean> = value => value === 'true';
const stringToInt: Normalizer<string, number> = value => Number.parseInt(value);
const stringToFloat: Normalizer<string, number> = value => Number.parseFloat(value);

export type NormalizerMap = {
    [string]: Normalizer<*, *>
};

export const formNormalizer: NormalizerMap = {
    paid: stringToBool,
    minLength: stringToInt,
    minShiftLength: stringToFloat,
};
```

And I get the following error:

```
11:     paid: stringToBool,
              ^ type application of polymorphic type: type `Normalizer`. Has some incompatible type argument with
7:     [string]: Normalizer<*, *>
                 ^ type application of polymorphic type: type `Normalizer`

    Type argument `B` is incompatible:
        2: const stringToBool: Normalizer<string, boolean> = value => value === 'true';
                                                  ^ boolean. This type is incompatible with
        3: const stringToInt: Normalizer<string, number> = value => Number.parseInt(value);
                                                 ^ number
```

Is it possible to do something like this with a polymorphic type?

Comment: If each property has a different type, it's pretty much by definition not a generic dictionary object. It seems like trying to define it as `NormalizerMap` is just not correct in this case.

Comment: This is the same as `{a: "foo", b: 123, c: true}`. It is rather a record than a collection. Polymorphic means that the type variables `A` and `B` are each bound to the same type within every map instance.